# "unrecognized expression: . " with filter

Tags: jquery, filter

I sometimes get an error of...

> Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: div.

code is

```
divs.filter('div.' + menuID).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
```

I have also tried

```
divs.filter('.' + menuID).show('slide', {direction: 'right'}, 200);
```

Comment: Whats the value of menuID?

Comment: It looks like `menuID` is blank.

Answer (score 3):

menuID is null, or something else that when coerced into a string becomes ''.

You should add protection to ensure that this code is not run when menuID is null or undefined or empty string.